# sql syntax in django

Tags: sql, django

I wanna use sql query in djnago. How send parameter to sql query from recieve parameter from function, for example my code is :

```
def products_filter(request, product, selling):
    all_product = Product.objects.raw("select * from product where product={{product}};")
```

How can I use product and selling in sql query??

Comment: why not just use filter? Product.objects.filter(product=product, selling=selling)

Comment: my real query in my project is complex, it is for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product.objects.raw("select * from product where product= %s", [product])`

or

`Product.objects.raw("select * from product where product= %s and selling= %s ", [product, selling])` 
should do

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/